# Erlang can't locate dependent applications when debugging

Tags: erlang

I have an Erlang application that runs fine outside the debugger.

But when I try to debug it, it fails. It can't any dependent applications other than the ones that are "built in" to Erlang (e.g., crypto).

For example, here it can't find ranch

```
Error in process <0.63.0> on node 'test_node1398822489915@tppllc-Mac-Pro' with exit value: {{badmatch,{error,{"no such file or directory","ranch.app"}}},[{presence,start,0,[{file,"presence.erl"},{line,7}]}]}
```

When I run it not in the debugger, it can find it, and the application works. I use the same -pa paths to point to the dependent directories for both debugging and non-debugging runs.

Comment: Exactly how are you launching your code with and without the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a bug with the IntellIJ Erlang plugin. It didn't pass the same parameters to erl in debug mode vs non-debug mode.

I reported it, and it was fixed:

https://github.com/ignatov/intellij-erlang/commit/1b400063df1e6dc92fde8aa23f852710775c4460